# Choice of loss function in correlation matrix prediction

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, prediction, heavy-tailed

There is a random vector $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_p)$, with $p$ large, $E[X]=0$ and $V[X_j]=1\ \forall \, j=1,\ldots,p$, but the correlations are different from zero. We cannot assume multivariate normality for $X$ (the marginal distributions are slightly skewed and heavy-tailed, as common in financial data).

Say we have a training set of $n$ realizations of the vector $X$, and we have some method of estimating the $p\times p$ correlation matrix. The goal is to compare the performance of several methods for predicting the correlation matrix in new data (hold-out/validation set).

*What is a good loss function between the estimated covariance matrix and the observed covariance matrix in the hold-out set?* So far, to my mind come 1. a predictive quasi-normal log-likelihood, 2. sum of absolute/squared errors between the off-diagonal elements of the estimated correlation matrix and the observed correlation matrix of the held-out data. Any better suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by predictive quasi-normal log-likelihood? quasi-likelihood certainly has its roots in estimation, but for prediction, maximum quasi-likelihood predictions are the same as conventional maximum likelihood. Plus I don't understand how a prediction would give you an estimate of correlation...

Comment: You might want to look at [robust statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics).

Comment: My goal is to estimate the correlation matrix on the training set, and to compare this estimate with the empirical correlation matrix of the validation set. By predictive quasi-normal log-likelihood I mean the log-likelihood of the validation set data under a (mis-specified) normal model, using the correlation matrix estimated on the training data.